# spring boot,Where's the Root WebApplicationContext and Servlet WebApplicationContext

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I use spring-boot-starter-web 1.5.17.I can't find any auto configuration about build Root WebApplicationContext and Servlet WebApplicationContext.

When not use spring boot,we need do this

```
public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/"};
}


@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[]{SecurityAdminConfig.class, DataSourceConfig.class, JavaConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[]{WebMvcConfig.class};
}
//controller、service
```

I know WebMvcAutoConfiguration do a lot of spring MVC configuration,but i can't find about auto build Root WebApplicationContext and Servlet WebApplicationContext.

```
public abstract class AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
    extends AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected WebApplicationContext createRootApplicationContext() {
    Class<?>[] configClasses = getRootConfigClasses();
    if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(configClasses)) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootAppContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootAppContext.register(configClasses);
        return rootAppContext;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected WebApplicationContext createServletApplicationContext() {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext servletAppContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    Class<?>[] configClasses = getServletConfigClasses();
    if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(configClasses)) {
        servletAppContext.register(configClasses);
    }
    return servletAppContext;
}


protected abstract Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses();


protected abstract Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses();
```

}

How can know this beans go Root WebApplicationContext or Servlet WebApplicationContext?

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf6I2.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, by default, a single application context in a Spring Boot web (or otherwise) application. It is created by SpringApplication when your application starts.

Comment: so by default,spring boot build Root WebApplicationContext?

Comment: if i need build Servlet WebApplicationContext,I need extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer?

Comment: There's no distinction between a root web application context and a servlet web application context in Spring Boot. It will, by default, create a single web application context for you when you application starts. You can create a child context if you wish by using `SpringApplicationBuilder`. You should not be sub-classing either `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` or `AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer`. I recommend asking another question that describes what you're trying to do at a higher level. Your current solution is not appropriate for Spring Boot.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson and do you know why it was decided to keep everything in the same application context instead of keeping them separate? Do you have any useful references about this?

Comment: It was a design decision made in the early days of Spring Boot. Having a context hierarchy adds complexity and not everyone will get any benefit from it. As such, it seems better to make it opt-in rather than something that everyone has to use.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it would be this:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder()
          .parent(ParentConfig.class).web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
          .child(WebConfig.class).web(WebApplicationType.SERVLET)
          .sibling(RestConfig.class).web(WebApplicationType.SERVLET)
          .run(args);
    }
}
```

I have taken it from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-context-hierarchy):
However, it is still not clear why by default everything is in the same context..
Also, I am not sure if that's fine that other beans created by WebMvcAutoconfiguration will be shared across all child contexts.